# How do I limit the number of cores used in the build process by catkin?

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been building groovy using the instructions from the wiki. My processor is an i5, 2 cores, 4 threads. Building PCL is a huge CPU hog and my system takes a few hours when all 4 threads are being almost fully used throughout. The problem is, my laptop tends to overheat and shut down when it gets to critical temp because of all this work (yes, the room temperature isn't helping). I was wondering if someone could tell me where catkin picks the "-jX" value from? It uses -j4 at the moment. I was wondering if reducing it to a -j3 or a -j2 might help keep the temperature down. It might take longer, but I can leave it overnight knowing that it isn't going to shut down after overheating.

During normal usage, my system is at about 45*c, so building PCL does take quite some work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59031/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-cores-used-in-the-build-process-by-catkin?/) by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't specify the numbers of jobs explicitly with `-jn` for `n` jobs when calling `make` or `catkin_make`, Catkin gets the number of jobs from the `ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS` environment variable. From the `catkin_make` help:

```
  -j [JOBS], --jobs [JOBS]
                        Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run
                        simultaneously. Defaults to the environment variable
                        ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS and falls back to the number of CPU
                        cores.
```

If you want to use `n` jobs by default, you can do the following before building a catkin project in catkin version 0.5.63:

```
export ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS=n
```

This is currently considered a compatibility bug, since for rosbuild, this should be:

```
export ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS=-jn
```

In the future versions of catkin, I believe the second option above will be the correct one. See this ticket here: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/335

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-24**:
This is not a good variable to depend on probably since it is `ROS_` prefixed, I would just advise using `make`'s own arguments to achieve this: `catkin_make -j1 ...`

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-25**:
Yeah, I think you're right, this environment variable is far too convenient and saves time for the user  so it's probably going to be removed from catkin in the future...

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-25**:
@jbohren catkin strives to be ROS agnostic, it picks up the `ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS` environment variable as a convenience. I doubt it will ever be removed, but since many people will find this Q/A I think we should recommend that they use tools we don't maintain to solve the problem, aka make -jn

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-25**:
I'd expect `ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS` to be removed from catkin, or at least renamed to `CATKIN_PARALLEL_JOBS`. I was surprised when catkin picked up my `ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS` environment variable. Partially because I know catkin intends to be unaware of ROS, but also because it interpreted it differently.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-25**:
`MAKEFLAGS` is probably yet a better option, but `catkin_make` currently clobbers this option, so I opened a ticket about changing that: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/400